# NSData length - Implicit conversion loses integer precision

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a little problem that I do not understand.

I looked on the Internet but I do not see where is my mistake.

```
id manufacturerData = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey];
if (manufacturerData) {
    const uint8_t *bytes = [manufacturerData bytes];
    int len = [manufacturerData length];
    // skip manufacturer uuid
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes+2 length:len-2];
```

> Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int'

Comment: Read the error message. The solution is right there in front of your eyes. The compiler told you what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your `manufacturerData` variable's type should be `NSData`, not `id`.

Look at the docs for `NSData`. What is the return type for the `length` property? Now look at the type you are using. See the difference?

Always use the proper data type.

You can also use the `subdataWithRange:` method instead of using the bytes.

```
NSData *manufacturerData = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey];
if (manufacturerData) {
    NSUInteger len = [manufacturerData length];
    // skip manufacturer uuid
    NSRange *dataRange = NSMakeRange(2, len - 2);
    NSData *data = [manufacturerData subdataWithRange:dataRange];
}
```